# 'Can't locate file.pl in @INC...' error in Perl

Tags: perl, module, require

I have a folder with several `.pl` files that run through `main.pl`. I have successfully had these working by using `require 'file.pl';` at the beginning of the main file. I have used some modules, too, without issue.

I am now trying to use a 'home-made' module, but when I add `use Add::Location::CSearch qw(c_search);` to the top of the file that it is being used in (or the top of the main file) and run the main file, it produces the `Can't locate file.pl in @INC...` error with `file.pl` being the first file in the `require` list in the main file.

From how I understand it, after adding the `use` line it now tries to find all the `require` in that same directory. The `(@INC contains: ...)` at the end of the error message lists some library/module folders. It also has `.` at the end for the current directory.

I hope I have explained this well; it is confusing! I don't know why this happens and how to solve it, so I would be grateful for any ideas.

Edit: Sample Code

```
main.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl
package testpack;

use lib '/hlib/...';
use Add::DB;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);
use strict;
use warnings;

require 'file1.pl';
require 'file2.pl'; 
require 'file3.pl';

.
.
.

file1.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl
package testpack;
use Add::Location::CSearch qw(c_search);
```

This is all that really counts for the problem... the rest of the files have working code that calls subroutines etc.

Comment: Is your module name also `Add::Location::CSearch`. I mean what does package statement say?. Is it `package Add::Location::CSearch;` ? Also check whether your folder is in @INC using `perl -V`.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for that module and it said to write exactly what I have done (I did not create the module). I didn't think the folder that I've put my .pl files in needed to be in \@INC as I'm just writing a program - it ran before without needing to be in \@INC

Comment: provide your sample code containing `use` and `require`

Comment: anyone else have any ideas? :(

Comment: "From how I understand it, after adding the use line it now tries to find all the require in that same directory" this is not true.  `use`ing a module has no effect on where Perl looks for modules... unless that module manipulates `@INC`, the list of where Perl looks for modules.  In the error message, Perl lists all the directories its looking for.  Where is `file.pl`?  Is it in the same directory as your `main.pl` program?

Comment: yes they are in the same directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your setup I can't be sure, but I'm going to throw something out there.

I suspect what's going on is `main.pl` and `file1.pl` are all in the same directory.  `require 'file1.pl'` is working because you've been doing `perl main.pl` from that directory.  Perl is finding `file1.pl` because `.` is in `@INC`, the list of where it looks for modules.

Now you're developing a new module.  You've changed directories to where you're developing that module, and maybe you're running `perl /path/to/main.pl`.  Perl can no longer find `file1.pl` because the current directory is different.

The typical solution for this is to use [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin) and `use lib` to put the directory where your `main.pl` resides into `@INC`.  Then it can find other libraries in that same directory no matter what directory you run `main.pl` from.

Comment: oh that's interesting - i was running it from the same directory but I will try adding the path/directory to see if that works, thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't really explain the behavior as described in the question (the error hinges on whether `use Add::Location::CSearch` is present).  Still, you could be right.

Comment: didnt work I'm afraid - can't say I know why as I'd have thought that that is a pretty explicit way of telling perl where to look :/

Comment: @bladepanthera Expand on "didn't work" please.  What did you try?

Comment: ah sorry, added use lib 'pathname' to main.pl with the path name of the directory that main.pl and the other .pl files are in

Comment: @bladepanthera A simple thing to try is to `cd` into the directory with `main.pl` in it and try to run it.  Does it work?  Then `cd` somewhere else and try again.  Does it not work?  If the first works and the second does not, then it's definitely an `@INC` issue.

Comment: @bladepanthera Was your included pathname in the error message about what was in `@INC` at the time?  If so, check for typos.

Comment: I'm in that directory. if I take out that extra line in the file1.pl then the whole program works, but as I would like to be able to use the module it doesn't really help me to exclude it... as to why it would then affect the require file statements, I'm not sure...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16918/discussion-between-schwern-and-bladepanthera)

Comment: @dan1111 `use Add::Location::CSearch` was a red herring.  It just happened that while developing the module was the first time `main.pl` was run from outside its own directory.

Comment: to conclude how problem was solved, added *correct* path name to `main.pl` using `use lib 'file\directory';` thanks to schwern!

Answer (score 0):

if like me you are here and used Notepad++ with NppExec, I may have the good answer for you:

go into NppExec options:
plugins > NppExec
clic on "Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"

the thing is I'm sure it was the only thing I changed but when I disable this option I don't get the error anymore ...

hth someone