# Gitolite with LDAP not working

Tags: git, ldap, gitolite

I am new to gitolite. I am trying to do a very simple test with gitolite. I have setup my repository called "test_repo". Please note that I have not modified anything else otherthan what I have stated below.  I can see this repo in gitweb. This is the repo configuration

```
repo test_repo
    RW+     =   @all
```

Now I want to clone this repo. I have ldap access to server. By my understanding of @all, it should allow me to do this.

when I issue

```
git clone git@myserver:repositories/test_repo.git 
#I know this is wrong. But I just wanted to test as the above did not work
```

or

```
git clone git@myserver:test_repo.git
```

its asking for password. I have followed this guide http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/05/31/how-to-create-own-git-server-with-gitolite-and-gitweb-in-ubuntu/, which does not set a password for git user

When I issue

`git clone myname@myserver:test_repo.git`

I am getting the following error

```
fatal: 'test_repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tired to clone the default repo "test_repo.git". But I am getting the same error.

I also tired this

```
git clone myname@myserver:/home/git/repositories/testing.git
```

then cloning is working. But when I do `git push -u origin master` some modified files I am getting

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
```

**Note**: I have not added any user in conf file

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 git clone myname@myserver:/home/git/repositories/testing.git
```

- that completely bypass gitolite, which isn't called
- use the wrong account 'myname' which has no right to read the git account folders.

What should work is:

```
 git clone git@myserver:test_repo.git
 or
 git clone git@myserver/test_repo.git
```

You shouldn't specify the 'repositories' folder (gitolite knows where the repo is supposed to be)

That supposes that `ssh -Tvvv git@myserver` works (ie do not ask password).
Make that ssh work first, and then try again the `git clone`.

---

As I say in the comment, LDAP *and* ssh are both authentication mechanism, so you can use one **or the other, not both**:

- Https + LDAP + gitolite: [**see an example here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309).
- Or SSH + gitolite

If the ssh works, but the clone doesn't work, then you need to have a look in the gitolite logs at `~git/.gitolite/logs`

> I could not find anything useful in the log. Moreover I did a `tail -f` of the log file. Its not even updated when I try to clone.

That means **the issue is on the ssh level, not calling properly gitolite**: that is in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and **happens if you add an ssh key manually directly in it, instead of adding through the `keys` folder of the `gitolite-admin` repo and pushing back that repo to the gitolite server** (which triggers the update of said `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys file`).

> I think that could be the reason. I have no idea what just happened. I can even clone `gitolite-admin`, in admin server (this was working earlier).
>   I will re install every thing (because I think I messed up a lot with config files by now).

Comment: ssh -Tvvv git@myserver asks for password

Comment: please note that the client which I am trying to login is not the admin system. Also I have not added the keys of this system.

Comment: I dont want to add the ssh because it means that every have to do so. I would like ldap to do authentication

Comment: For testing I added the keys.so `ssh git@myserver` is working. But  when I use : then it shows the same error as before. When I use \ it shows `fatal repository does not exist`

Comment: @knightrider You can have apache + LDAP (+ gitolite) as I illustrates in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309, or ssh + gitolite. But not ssh + LDAP + gitolite. ssh authenticates. Or LDAP authenticates. Not both. So when cloning a repo with an ssh url, you always use '`git`', not '`user`'.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think we can ignore LDAP now as all the above assumed ssh. I still cant figure out why the cloning is not working

Comment: @knightrider If the ssh works, but the clone doesn't work, then you need to have a look in the gitolite logs at `~git/.gitolite/logs`

Comment: I could not find anything useful in the log. Moreover I did a `tail -f` of the log file. Its not even updated when I try to clone

Comment: @knightrider good information! That means the issue is on the ssh level, not calling properly gitolite: that is in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and happens if you add an ssh key manually directly in it, instead of adding through the keys folder of the `gitolite-admin` repo and pushing back that repo to the gitolite server (which triggers the update of said `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file). So, what does your `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` looks like?

Comment: I think that could be the reason. I have no idea what just happened. I can even clone gitolite-admin, in admin server (this was working earlier). I will re install every thing (because I think I messed up a lot with config files by now). I will try the ldap method now as I redoing everything. Please keep a watch on this thread in case I require any more info

Comment: @knightrider I [always keep a watch every single day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309) ;) I have edited the answer to reflect the findings so far.

Comment: finally after re installation it is working. I added user using gittolite and things are good. So what is not working is gitweb using ldap and git using gitolite and ssh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34681/discussion-between-knightrider-and-vonc)

Comment: @knightrider unfortunately, I cannot access the chat while at work.

Comment: I dont know much about apache configuration. But I have an important question. I want to give unrestricted access to all users preferably using gitolite. Is this possible. But for now, when ever I want to give a user access to git (using ssh), I have to add his keyfile using gitolite. By using ldap, can this be eliminated (In future may be this is not the case).

Comment: @knightrider yes, ldap would allow you to not worry about ssh key, but that supposes an Apache setup. That is what I describe in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17985744/6309

Comment: I am trying not to use the certificate. Also I cannot locate the gitolite-shell. In the bin directory I can only find gitolite

Comment: @knightrider certificate is for https access. Simply remove all SSL lines and you won't have to use a certificate. In gitolite v3, I do have `gitolite-shell` in addition of `gitolite` in my `<gitolite-install-dir>/bin` folder.

Comment: I am using version V3.5. I searched in installdir bin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /bin and /sbin. its not there

Comment: I found that in installdir/src/. I will create a link in bin

Comment: @knightrider not sure if that will work. It seems like a spotty buggy installation to me. Here is my gitolite installation script: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L27-L53. I use a `"${github}/install" -to "${gtl}/bin" ; GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME= gitolite setup -pk "${H}/.ssh/gitoliteadm.pub"` to install gitolite in `${gtl}/bin` (which is in my `$PATH`)

Comment: gitolite was in bin, but not gitolite-shell. Also gitolite was actually a link to source. Finally I have configured my htdocs http://pastebin.com/4bVFCCCx . Now when I try `git clone http://<myserverip>:7777/hgit/testing.git` its showing `fatal ***service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

Comment: @knightrider do you see that error message *after* having passed the LDAP authentication dialog? Or before? And beware that `AuthBasicProvider` is supposed to reference an LDAP *alias* define before-hand.

Comment: It did not ask for authentication. Is the url correct? I am using `AuthBasicProvide ldap` and an `AuthLDAPURL`. Its shown in pastebin.com/4bVFCCCx. These two lines were copy pasted from gitweb conf file which works

Comment: @knightrider the url is correct. "from gitweb conf file which works" you mean mine? Do you see anything relevant in the `githttp_..._log` files?

Comment: No I mean my gitweb conf file. I found the problem. It was access issues with the link I create. I fixed it. Now its asking for username and password. After I enter that I have more errors (when will this end). I have pasted the output of errorlog in http://pastebin.com/FEett4mu

Comment: @knightrider `Can't locate Gitolite/Rc.pm`...  I had that with old `require` directive in my [`gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/commit/7117962546d7fee0404f29e54720dbf4142c4ba9#L6R1). Do you have a `use Gitolite::Rc;` in your [`gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L22-L27)?

Comment: I dont have a gitweb.conf.pl. Should I create it? Where would this be located?

Comment: @knightrider first look in your gitweb where 'Rc' is mentioned.

Comment: I checked /usr/share/gitweb and /home/git/gitolite there is no Rc.pm

Comment: @knightrider in http://pastebin.com/4bVFCCCx, you seem to be missing a [`DocumentRoot` (see link)](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L59) which should point to your gitweb folder. In there you need to add a [`gitweb_config.perl` (link)](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl) which is automatically interpreted by gitweb if found. That file can include a [`gitweb.conf.pl` (link)](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl)

Comment: My gitweb conf is in another file located in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb` The contents of that are here http://pastebin.com/6ztM4rk3. I have created the file `gitweb_config.perl` with the following contents http://pastebin.com/r6v0YCmw. I strong doubt the contents of the previous are correct. What should `$home_link_str` and `$site_name` be. Is my assignment to them correct. I also created  `gitweb.conf.pl` with contents http://pastebin.com/RZzmREus

Comment: Both the files were created in `/usr/share/gitweb`. It giweb.conf.pl I modified the variables `$ENV{HOME}` `$ENV{GL_BINDIR}` `$ENV{GL_LIBDIR}` to point to correct locations. I did not remove the ssl stuff in that file. The error is same as before

Comment: @knightrider What is this http://pastebin.com/6ztM4rk3 conf file??? It doesn't look anything like http://pastebin.com/4bVFCCCx. You need one or the other, not both

Comment: May be I am completly wrong. This http://pastebin.com/6ztM4rk3 was created when I first created gitweb with gitolite. That file contains the ldap authentication for the web interface. The second one http://pastebin.com/4bVFCCCx I created by following your instructions. it was made by modifying httd.conf. It has no info about the gitweb. The second one was to handle `git clone ` etc from command line

Comment: this is the new error I get in the terminal where I try to log in `http://pastebin.com/eu88jJsg` and this is the error on error log `http://pastebin.com/HdzKHCP1`

Comment: what should be the values of `$home_link_str` and `$site_name` in gitweb_config.perl. Also There is Rc.pm file in my folder

Comment: @Vnoc I found the problem. For some reason the lib was not copied to bin directory while installation. SO I create a link. Now ldap is working. But there is a problem while pushing back

Comment: @knightrider progress. `$home_link_str` and `$site_name` are any value you would like to be displayed for the gitweb site. Those aren't likely to cause problem.

Comment: Yes atleast some progess. This is the error when I try to push `http://pastebin.com/N6kKmaP2`. I think if change the group of repository from git to ldap this will work. But is it a right thing to do ?

Comment: Every this is messed up. I just added a new repostiory using gitlite. After I pushed it gitweb is showing `Can't locate gitweb.conf.pl in @INC (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at gitweb_config.perl line 5.`

Comment: Also when I try to clone I am getting this error `FATAL: split conf set, gl-conf not present for 'testing'`

Comment: @knightrider At this stage, I would go back to the gitolite installation/initialization: making sure that works first (no link added).

Comment: you mean reinstall gitolite. if yes can you give a link to the article. I was using this http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/05/31/how-to-create-own-git-server-with-gitolite-and-gitweb-in-ubuntu/. But apparently this wont set links properly

Comment: @knightrider regarding the "`Can't locate gitweb.conf.pl`", what is the full content of your `gitweb_config.perl`? [See mine here](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl).

Comment: @knightrider I like [my method for installing gitolite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990402/gitolite-with-ldap-not-working/17991421?noredirect=1#comment26348502_17991421), but the [official doc is here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html).

Comment: Mine is like that `http://pastebin.com/LLXB679y`.  I will try your method. I just need to run that script right? Or should I edit something? my git server username is `git`. Should I change something to speciy this

Comment: @knightrider looks like mine. Try and use an absolute path in the '`use`' directive. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12513238/6309 is an interesting read.

Comment: @vnoc now the previous error is gone but its showing `FATAL: parse './gl-conf' failed: Permission denied`. Where is this file located

Comment: @knightrider in each bare repo in `~git/repostories/xxx.git`. If you have installed again gitolite, try and declare a new repo, push `gitolite-admin` and see if that new repo is created, with `gl-conf` inside.

Comment: I did not install I was waiting for this question in previous post.  I just need to run that script right? Or should I edit something? my git server username is git. Should I change something to speciy this

Comment: @knightrider `git` is fine. In your case, follow the official doc I mentioned before.

Comment: The installation is complete. I updated all the config files. Gitweb is working now. git clone is also working. In the default testing repo there is gl-conf. I will add a new project later. First I would like to fix the current main problem, `git push`. The error on the terminal where I try to push is http://pastebin.com/ZgQpc7Dz. Output of log is http://pastebin.com/yZfmHe0K

Comment: and output of `git config core.sharedRepository` is `true`. Also it possible to move to chat room now. This comment section is really big now

Comment: Even more ssh using gitolite is working. But when I do git push, it works and it changes the permission of some files. When I fixed the permission gitweb is not showing any projects

Comment: @knightrider I mainly manage that by making sure all my process are managed by the same user.

Comment: @VnoC Since gitolite is causing too much problem, especially changing the file permissions I am thinking of avoiding it completely. ie Just gitweb. Is this a terrible idea in my use case? are the any good alternatives to gitweb, which has inbuilt support for ldap?

Comment: @knightrider I agree gitolite isn't mandatory, and is not linked to ldap. So (http + ldap) + gitweb should be enough.

Comment: I will try removing gitolite. I think your apache configuration had some comments to use this without gitolite. I will contact you if I again run into troubles. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Thanks to you. Everything is working except http. Over ssl I can add repositories push them etc, there is no problem at all. over http it shows some error. I think is a minor error. The error is `File does not exist: /var/www/hgit`. The httpd conf is http://pastebin.com/jnL6bZvg

Comment: @knightrider seems [similar to my config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L112), but can you try to add a '`/`' at the end of the `ScriptAlias` line? `ScriptAlias /hgit /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/`

Comment: I tried that the result is same. Is there any log I should check?

Comment: @knightrider see also http://serverfault.com/a/393095/783 and http://serverfault.com/q/412314/783 as configuration examples.

Comment: There was some strange problem. After I restarted apache it was not working. But after restarting the system its working. Thankyou very much. Finally solved

Comment: @knightrider Sounds great! I am still curious why gitolite wasn't playing along though...

Comment: I lost hope in gitolite. Not because of http access but because when I push it changes the file permissions. Without it, its working great. May its because I downloaded the latest branch

Comment: @knightrider no, I don't have any issue with it, but I only use *one* account to manage everything, so I don't have permission issue.

Comment: hi I have new problem over http after I updated the system. It is showing `File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs`. I followed the instructions on `http://cobwebs.id.au/?p=110`. Now it shows `File does not exist: /var/www/hgit`. Any idea of the same?

Comment: I have gone back to previous stage. Now if I give port number in the url it shows error with `htdocs` otherwise it shows error with `hgit`

Comment: @knightrider for any new issue, it is best to create a separate question, which would detail the new context (and have a link back to this question).

Answer (score 1):

just try

ssh git@hostname-or-ip

This should not ask password; it can ask passphrase. This will also emit list of repositories you have access to.

BTW - username@localhost in git clone command is grossly wrong

Comment: I tired `ssh git@ip`. Its asking for password

Comment: Strangely if I do ssh git@localhost its showing what you suggested

Comment: then your clone url should be  "git clone user@hostname:repo.git"

Comment: another thing - there could be mismatch between ip and name. try cleaning up /etc/hosts. use correct dns server etc..etc; check ~/.ssh/config file. possibly paste is on stackoverflow

Comment: git clone myname@myserver:test_repo.git is not working. The output for this is updated in the post

Comment: I am directly giving the ip address

Comment: are localhost and ip-###-###-###-### really the same ?

Comment: Yes. I now have added the clients public key to authorized keys of server. So now I can ssh without password. But still the error is the same